# How to use Contabo S3 storage with AWS S3 SDK for C#?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, aws-sdk-net

I'm using the contabo S3 storage to integrate using AWS S3 SDK for C#. I've used the ServiceUrl as https://eu2.contabostorage.com/

Below is the sample source code I've used for client configuration.

```
AWSConfigsS3.UseSignatureVersion4 = false;
AmazonS3Client S3Client = new AmazonS3Client(Constants.AWSAccessKey, Constants.AWSSecretKey,
              new AmazonS3Config
                 {
                     ServiceURL = Constants.AWSServiceUrl,
                 });
PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest
{
    BucketName = Constants.AWSBucketName,
    Key = fileName,
    ContentType = "image/jpg"
};
using (var stream = new MemoryStream(DependencyService.Get<IMediaService>().ResizeImage(file.Path, 1024, 1024)))
{
    request.InputStream = stream;
    PutObjectResponse objectResponse = await S3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);
    return fileName;
}
```

When I run it, I always get exception as "No such host". I've also tried different region and signature version but the same error is coming. What can I do to make it working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[HttpPost("upload_file")]
public async Task<ActionResult> UploadFile(IFormFile file)
{
    string url = "";

    try
    {
        var accessKey = "xxxx";
        var secretKey = "xxxx";
        var bucketName = "xxxx";

        AmazonS3Config config = new AmazonS3Config();
        config.ServiceURL = "https://eu2.contabostorage.com";
        config.DisableHostPrefixInjection = true;
        config.ForcePathStyle = true;

        AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(
                accessKey,
                secretKey,
                config
                );

        ListBucketsResponse response = await s3Client.ListBucketsAsync();

        using (var newMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            file.CopyTo(newMemoryStream);
            PutObjectRequest request = new PutObjectRequest();
            request.BucketName = bucketName;
            request.Key = file.FileName;
            request.ContentType = file.ContentType;
            request.InputStream = newMemoryStream;
            await s3Client.PutObjectAsync(request);

            GetPreSignedUrlRequest requestGet = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest();
            requestGet.BucketName = bucketName;
            requestGet.Key = file.FileName;
            requestGet.Expires = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1);
            requestGet.Protocol = Protocol.HTTPS;
            url = s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(requestGet);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return StatusCode(500, Utils.errorMessage(ex));
    }
    return Ok(url);
}
```